# Are tags rendered differently in questions and comments on purpose?

Tags: discussion, tags, comments, markdown

I've noticed that if I write `[tag:tags]` in a question it renders like this in a question: [tags](/questions/tagged/tags). In a comments it looks differently (see the comment below).

Is it on purpose? Is this new, or was the behavior in comments and question always different?

Note: I noticed this at [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/), but I guess this is more-or-less consistent on the whole SO network.

Comment: This is how `[tag:tags]` looks in a comment: [tag:tags].

Comment: Btw hi Martin! This will look I'm talking to yourself!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is done intentionally to save some space. Comments should be lightweight. They do not support displaying tags or images at all.

Comment: On the other hand: I wish the rendering in questions was like those in the comments! (It could then still show the tag summary on hover, though I never saw the need for that either. Actually, I think the whole tag thing is the worst deviation from Markdown, but apparently many like them and even edit posts from others to add them.)

Comment: @The but I do ^^

Comment: @The, I love you. ;-)

Comment: We're only talking about CSS: on SE it's foreground & background colour, borders and some light spacing.  I can't believe that such styling would make comments any less lightweight... is this really the "official" answer?

Comment: @eggyal that's not about space in CSS files or something like that. But tags looks like small images, and images are also disabled in comments.