# Apply post-tag CSS class to shorthand tag links in comments

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags, comments, hyperlinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are tags renderred differently in questions and comments on purpose?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129254/are-tags-renderred-differently-in-questions-and-comments-on-purpose)

The editing help explains that [comment formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) supports shorthand links, including:

> `[tag:tagname]` and `[meta-tag:tagname]` – link to the given tag's page. Link text is the name of the tag. `meta-tag` only works on meta sites.

Whereas such links are formatted with the `post-tag` CSS class in [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tags), which styles them as [tags](/questions/tagged/tags), they are not so formatted in comments—instead just appearing as normal links; it is therefore not always evident that one is referring to a tag without explicitly stating `"tag [tag:foo]"`.

Please apply the `post-tag` class to such shorthand links in comments.

Comment: Related: [Are tags renderred differently in questions and comments on purpose?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129254)

Comment: @TimStone: Agreed, that is related.  I have commented on that question's accepted (and only) answer, as I'm surprised by it.  Perhaps this question can be closed as a dupe.

Comment: This is still a valid (non-dupe) request, that was just a brief explanation of why they aren't the same as they are in questions. That doesn't mean that they can't be made to look distinct, though. See also [balpha's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94180) upon implementing this.

Comment: @TimStone: Aha, then it is at very least by design.  I will remove the [tag:bug] tag (and therein lies a perfect case in point).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Tim Stone already noted, this is a deliberate decision. We don't want comments to look like this:

[image: a screenshot of a comment that includes several styled tags]

Comment: Are unciorns similar to magical, weaponized ponies? ;-)