# Display tags in comments as in posts (questions\answers)

Tags: feature-request, tags, design

If I write `[meta-tag:tag]` in question it will be displayed this way

[tag](/questions/tagged/tag)

but in comment it will be displayed like hyperlink: [tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag).

I suggest to display tag links in comments the same as in posts (questions\answers).

Comment: [Are tags rendered differently in questions and comments on purpose?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129254/307988)

Comment: @Cai OK, thanks for your link. So I want to reconsider current behaviour. 
I'm aware that this might get [meta-tag:status-declined].

Comment: Sure, that's why I didn't close vote, I was just adding a relevant discussion :)

Answer (score 5):

#### No.

[because](/questions/tagged/because)no[one](/questions/tagged/one)wants[to](/questions/tagged/to)see[comments](/questions/tagged/comments)messed[up](/questions/tagged/up)like[this](/questions/tagged/this).

As [*Martin.* said](/a/129256/350567),

> This is done intentionally to save some space. **Comments should be lightweight.** They do not support displaying tags or images at all.

People have always complained that inline blocks are intrusive, [especially the <kbd> tag](/q/1939/350567). So supporting tags in comments will only render them less readable. It makes no improvements at all.

This is what you may see as tags in comments:

> [image: Aftermath]
> Image credit to [Cai](/u/307988).

Comment: [I was bored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYNnp.png)

Answer (score 1):

If the tag is not displayed well, then it would at least be possible to have some other hints that it is a tag. For instance, the block in HTML could be displayed with the same background color as the tag within posts, and a hoover could display the normal pop-up that is displayed when hoovering over a tag that is displayed the usual way.

Currently the tag is simply displayed as a link, which gives no hint whatsoever that a tag is meant. Even displaying the text `tag:` would be beneficial. Such a measure would not mess up the makeup of the comment.